# Filter items of relation on query

Tags: google-app-maker

Given scenario below:

**Models:**

```
Projects
Tasks
```

and

**Relationship:**

```
Projects (one) <--> (many) Tasks
```

I have an accordion with the datasource that only shows Projects with uncompleted tasks.
(e.g., query.filters.Tasks.Completed._equals = false)

In the accordion detail I have a list where I only want to show tasks that meet a certain criteria (eg. Task.Category = "Marketing" OR "Sales").

[image]

Is this possible, and if so, how would this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a dedicated datasource for filtered Tasks
2. Set it to manual load mode
3. Drop a table inside Accordion's details prototype
4. Bind the table to the datasource from the step #1
5. Add this snippet to the `onDataLoad` event of the Accordion's details prototype

```javascript
// Accordion details onDataLoad event handler
var ds = app.datasources.TasksFitered;
var projectKey = widget.datasource.item._key;

ds.query.filters.Category._in = ['Marketings', 'Sales'];
ds.query.filters.Project._key._equals = projectKey;
ds.load();
```

Most likely you'll need to unload the datasource on onDetach event of the details, to hide old results when user switches between projects:

```javascript
// Accordion details onDetach event handler
app.datasources.TasksFitered.unload();
```

Comment: Thank you Pavel. While this answers the question, there are also limitations to this approach. For example, in the Accordion ListPanel I have the Project name and then a grid with the two tasks (marketing & sales) and display the due date of that task. Expanding the detail will show the full task detail (as expected) The grid will not load properly on each Project's ListPanel, it will only use the data of the currently selected title. The other approach I can use is a new relation but then I imagine that slowing things down relating tasks to projects multiple times for each department

Comment: Hmm... do you have some restrictions in your system that force users to create exactly two Project Items of specific Category? If not, how do you decide which two tasks should be displayed Accordion's Row (opposed to Accordion's Details)?

Comment: No, there isn't a restriction. I am attempting to present the user with tasks only pertaining to their role (e.g. sales) and grouped under the project since they will be working on >20 projects simultaneously. The reason for the grid (chips) is so the user can see tasks that they need to take immediate action on or data that is regularly referenced. Certainly open to other suggested ways of approaching this.

Comment: I still don't clearly understand what pieces of data you want to display in Accordion's Row vs Accordion's Details. I think mock could help. You can update the Q by uploading an image with the mock.

Comment: Added an image.

Comment: Okay... Now it is almost clear. Let's say that some projects will have 5 related items of `Marketing` or `Sales` category. Do you need to show all five items both inside the Grid in the Accordion's Row and List inside Accordion's Details? How many related item do you expect project to have(10/100/1000/...)?

Comment: I don't think they necessarily would need to show all 5 related items. A project will likely have between 20-50 total task items, and each department/role (no more than 10 department/roles) would have between 2 and 5 tasks.

Comment: So, if you don't plan to show all related items in Accordion's Row you can consider to create Calculated Model to display some Project info and some most recent related items (maybe also total count of related items to hint users that they can find more by expanding details)